# Alphabet HiLo Guessing Game Not Working Properly (Python 3.11.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to do an alphabet version of the HiLo guessing game where it basically has the same concept but you guess a letter. After guessing correctly, it'll save to a text file with the date and time, as well as the number of guesses it took.

So far basically everything BUT my while loop works for this game. I tried looking online for some answers and follow that format they did, but it just doesn't work. I wrote hint messages with things such as "Your guess is too high, guess closer to Z" or "Your guess is too low, guess closer to A", but for some reason when I run it it just does "Your guess is too high, guess closer to Z" for like basically every letter in the alphabet that I guess.
For my error messages for inputs such as numbers and a lot of letters, sometimes it does the proper "Invalid answer" but sometimes it does the hint message of your guess is too high or too low. Kinda confused.

```
#Imports
from datetime import datetime
import random

#Class
class HiLo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.guesses = guesses
        self.guess_count = guess_count

    def __str__(self):
        return f"guesses = {self.guesses} guess_count = {self.guess_count}"

    def HiLogame():
        answer_opt = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        answer = random.choice(answer_opt)
        guess_count = 0
        guesses = []
        user_guess = input("Enter a letter (b/w A and Z): ").upper()
        guesses.append(user_guess)
        while user_guess != answer:
            if (len(user_guess) > 1):
                print("Invalid answer.")
                print()
                guess_count = guess_count + 1
                user_guess = input("Please guess again: ")
                guesses.append(user_guess)
                print()
            if not user_guess.isalpha():
                print("Invalid answer.")
                print()
                guess_count = guess_count + 1
                user_guess = input("Please guess again: ")
                guesses.append(user_guess)
                print()
            if (answer > user_guess):
                print("Your guess is too low.")
                print("Guess closer to A.")
                print()
                guess_count = guess_count + 1
                user_guess = input("Please guess again: ")
                guesses.append(user_guess)
                print()
            if (answer < user_guess):
                print("Your guess is too high")
                print("Guess closer to Z.")
                print()
                guess_count = guess_count + 1
                user_guess = input("Please guess again: ")
                guesses.append(user_guess)
                print()
        else:
                guess_count = guess_count + 1
                guesses.append(user_guess)
                print()
                print("You guessed correctly! The answer was:", answer)
                print("Your number of guesses:", guess_count)

        #Save guesses
        guess_file = open("guess_count.txt", mode='a')
        guess_file.write(str(guesses))
        guess_file.write('\n')
        guess_file.write(str(guess_count))
        guess_file.write(" guesses, ")
        guess_file.close()

    def dateandtime():
        guess_file = open("guess_count.txt", mode='a')
        guess_file.write(str(datetime.now()))
        guess_file.write('\n')
        guess_file.write('\n')
        guess_file.close()

#Calling
user_game = HiLo
user_game.HiLogame()
user_game.dateandtime()
```

Would really appreciate how to fix it up. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that `A` is the lowest and `Z` is the highest character in your game (`'A' < 'Z'`) because of their ASCII values.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `answer > user_guess` to `answer < user_guess` and  `answer < user_guess` to `answer > user_guess`.

See comment from [Michael Butcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717987/alphabet-hilo-guessing-game-not-working-properly-python-3-11-1#comment133574331_75717987) for explanation.